# How do I Flex a Safeview properly?

Tags: react-native

So I am trying to add a view inside of a Safeview. But the Flex option in the SafeView is not allowing me to add the view.

if I remove the flex, it cuts off at the bottom of the screen.

How do I resolve this?

```
import React from "react";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native";

function Screen({ children, style }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[styles.screen, style]}>
      <View style={style}>{children}</View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    flex: 1
  },

});

export default Screen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can put Vỉew into the SafeAreaView. I guess  props of `style` parameter when passing to this children has something incorrect.

Sample styles:

```
container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#fefefe',
    }
```

And the children view:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <IconsTitleHeader title={'Go Back'} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                        <Text>{"No internet connection"}</Text>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
```